# Can correlating features change the AUROC of a model trained on randomly shuffled labels?

Tags: correlation, random-forest, auc

I did a binary classification with a random forest on my dataset, where I removed all correlating features and figured I'd try out a sort of "negative control" and shuffle all labels randomly and retrain the model. My expectation was, that I'd get an AUROC of 0.5, which is what happened. But when I put the correlating features back into the dataset, I noticed the AUROC being at 0.3. I thought that was pure coincidence, due to the random shuffling of the labels, but I repeated the training 10 times over and the AUROC stayed around 0.3. I changed nothing else besides adding the correlating features and I can't explain this behavior.

I looked more into macro- and micro-average AUROCs and noticed that the micro-average is closer to the 0,5 (0.47), than the macro-average AUROC curve (0.3).
I found in a discussion [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/micro-average-vs-macro-average-performance-in-a-multiclass-classification-settin):

> In a multi-class classification setup, micro-average is preferable if you suspect there might be class imbalance.

Which is true for my dataset, since I've got about 1/3 of the positive class (class 1) and 2/3 of the negative class (class 0), but I don't understand if that is relevant in a setup with random labels. Does anyone have any idea what could be happening?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Is this in-sample or out-of-sample AUC?

Comment: Thanks! It is an out-of-sample AUC.